# variables retaining values after app close

Tags: android, variables, memory, default, reset

My app is retaining all of the variable values when it closes and this is effecting how it runs when reopened. Is there any way to reset them all upon app close? or is there a way to clean the app from memory when it is closed so to speak? For the moment I have just been setting all of the important variables "=0" in the last few lines of execution but I know there must be a correct way to doing this.

EDIT:

OK I thought that it would just be easier to reply here instead of individually to everyone.

The app is indeed staying alive in the background, I checked with advanced task killer. How would I get the ap to "Die" by presing the back button? I think this would be the easiest solution given how the app works:

open app > press start button > press stop button > results screen > press back button to exit.

so basically each time the app runs should be an independant execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the onPause, onResume, and onDestroy methods. onPause should save anything upon pausing, onResume should reload these values when it is resumed, and onDestroy will be called when your app closes. You can clean up stuff in onDestroy. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) link.

Answer (score 2):

You app is probably not closing but remaining in background. Check advanced task manager and see if the app is running or not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to familiarize yourself with the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

You could leverage `onResume()` to reset your variables; also note `onDestory()` and `onPause()`.

**UPDATE:**

Killing the application in its entirety each time the app moves to the background is an anti-pattern. You should really look at your application and follow the aforementioned activity lifecycle pattern and take the needed steps to insure your variables exist as you desire based on state.

Answer (score 1):

I like what @Alex and @Jack said. To add to that, also consider that you can call `finish()` in your `Activity` if you want to force it to close up and return to the last Activity. Going along with this, also consider the use of `setResult(int)` ([JavaDoc Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29))

You can also set a flag on the `Intent` when you call the `Activity` you are questioning about. A flag like **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY** could be helpful:

> If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished. This may also be set with the noHistory attribute.

List of [Intent Flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Uninitialized variables are bad. Don't do it. ALWAYS manually reset variables before using them for the first time.

Comment: I don't think he is having an issue with uninitialized variables.

Comment: I don't see how the OP can be read in any other way: he closes the app and, when he reopens it, his variables have the same value as when it was closed. What's happening is probably that the app was just placed in the background instead of closing but the root of the issue is that the OP wanted to restart the program. This means that, in a sane execution path, all variables should have been reinitialized and it isn't the case. Ergo: he isn't initializing his variables before using them.

Comment: Look at the main question: *Is there any way to reset them all upon app close?* -- At the end he says he is setting all the variables back to zero, which means he either expected the activity to `finish()` or he is not familiar with `onPause()` and `onResume()`. Uninitialized variables usually causes problems like unexpected output OR exceptions being thrown, neither of which were mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

the onResume() method will let you reset the variables when the program resumes, but will also do it when you return to the activity unless you add the logic that says you are coming from in the app, not the home page. Maybe onRestart() is what you really need? I'm not positive, but it's possible with onResume.