# How to retain a variable's value after exiting application

Tags: java, android, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [variables retaining values after app close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913819/variables-retaining-values-after-app-close)

I am relatively new to android and java, so I am sorry if this a stupid question. I have an android application that allows a user to take pictures and save them. I am saving the pictures as Attachment 0, Attachment 1 etc.

I am using an integer to decide the attachment number and this int gets incremented every time an attachment is created. my photos are getting saved properly with the proper names, but when I close my application the value of the integer gets reset to 0 and the already saved attachments get overwritten. How do I prevent the integer from resetting on closing and opening the application ? Thanks !

Comment: use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putInt(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913819/variables-retaining-values-after-app-close

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save the `int` value, then reload it in `onCreate`.

There is an excellent bit of code [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for you to learn from, and I'll give you a bit of pseudocode to get you going:

```
onCreate:
    prefs = <load shared preferences>;
    yourInt = prefs.getInt("name of your int", 0);
    // do whatever with yourInt

onPause: // maybe not onPause, maybe you want to save each time it changes?
    prefs = <load shared preferences>;
    editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("name of your int", yourInt);
    editor.commit();
```

And that should do it! That's the basic concept of `SharedPreferences`, and from that, I think you'll have no problem adapting the tutorials above to your purpose.